# Prevent context menu from launching until content script gets a response back

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

*(I will refer to content script as **cs.js** and background.js as **ba.js**)*

**Scenario:**

`oncontextmenu` click, I need to determine the url of the page and its blocked status and send it to **ba.js**. Code (**cs.js**):

```
var triggered = false;

window.oncontextmenu = function(event){
    if(triggered) return;

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        url: window.location.href,
        blocked: isBlocked
    }, function(response){  // after work has been done
        triggered = true;           
        triggerEvent(window, "contextmenu", event); // line A
        triggered = false; // line C
    });

    return false; // line B
};
```

The problem is that by the time I get the response, context menu has already been shown to the user **without** my desired message (since I didn't get back the response, which implies **ba.js** hadn't completed `chrome.contextMenus.update` call yet) Therefore, as a solution I have:

1. Returned `false` to prevent it from being shown (line B)
2. Used a `trigger` boolean to make sure message is not sent again when I `triggerEvent` (global) on line A.
3. And then reset `trigger` boolean on line C.

However this approach does not work. Therefore, I need a way to:

> **On context menu action, send a message from the pertaining cs.js to ba.js to update the context menu based on certain parameters available only to the cs.js and then, ONLY on receiving the message back, show the context menu to the user.**

**Note:** I have already tried using `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` and other friends (so that I can detect the current page on which the user is present, and therefore get the necessary parameters myself), however, I could not get this to work using them as well.

**`ba.js`**`onMessage`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse){   
    if(typeof msg.url !== undefined){
        url = msg.url; // global

        isBlocked = msg.blocked; // global
        action = isBlocked ? "Unblock" : "Block"; // global

        chrome.contextMenus.update("blockSite", { // update action
            title: action + " this site"
        });

        sendResponse("done");  // send confirmation
    }
});
```

`triggerEvent` code:

```
function triggerEvent(node, eventName, obj){
    var ev = new CustomEvent(eventName, obj || {});

    node.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
```

**UPDATE**:

So, I used `onActivated` and this time it worked pretty well, apart from one big issue:

If I open a new tab, then click site tile/type site address and the site opens. Then, the `onActivated` listener doesn't fire (which is obvious of course.)
I can't use `onUpdated` for this because it will fire whenever an iframe is updated even in a page which is not active at the moment.

What can I do to correct this fault?

Comment: I don't know much about chrome extensions, nor about what you are trying to achieve, but can't you do this request before the contextmenu event? Then **cs.js** will already know the value of `isBlocked`at the time the event fires. I mean, it seems you are looking for the `location.href` to determine `isBlocked` so you should be able to get it at load. Maybe you can then just update it twice, in the background (which I guess is some sort of database or something), and on the page.

Comment: @Kaiido If I send a message to **ba.js** *before* the context menu event, then it would send a message whenever the page just loads, not when it's focused.

Comment: What you're asking for is not possible (yet?), but has been proposed as a feature request: [Issue 60758: Allow contextMenus to be updated with context specific information prior to rendering](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=60758).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't trigger the built-in context menu in Chrome pragmatically. Because it's one of the user gestures that Chrome uses to grant certain temporary permissions like `activeTab`.

Use `tabs.onActivated` and `tabs.onUpdated` event listeners to keep track of the changes in the active tab and update the context menu accordingly.

- persistent background page (default mode):

  ```
  var activeTabId;

  chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(info) { updateContextMenu(info.tabId) });

  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {
      if (tabId == activeTabId) {
          updateContextMenu(tabId);
      }
  });

  function updateContextMenu(tabId) {
      activeTabId = tabId;
      chrome.tabs.get(tabId, function(tab) {
          var isBlocked = checkBlockedState(tab.url);
          chrome.contextMenus.update("blockSite", {
              title: (isBlocked ? "Unblock" : "Block") + " this site"
          });
      });
  }
  ```
- event page (`"persistent" : false`):

  ```
  chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(info) { updateContextMenu() });

  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {
      chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
          if (tabs[0].id == tabId) {
              updateContextMenu();
          }
      });
  });

  function updateContextMenu() {
      chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
          var isBlocked = checkBlockedState(tabs[0].url);
          chrome.contextMenus.update("blockSite", {
              title: (isBlocked ? "Unblock" : "Block") + " this site"
          });
      });
  }
  ```